# Go check if file is a text file

Tags: file, go

how do I check if a file is a text file, not images, video nor other than a text file?

what I already tried is to check a-Z 0-9 and special chars is contained in the file

Comment: You could check it's mime-type? With e.g. https://golang.org/pkg/mime/

Comment: I found this: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/util#IsTextFile , or if you've already pulled the bytes: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/util#IsText

Comment: You can try http.DetectContentType, and check if the content type is text/plain.

Comment: thank you all, i use util from @RayfenWindspear

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are really doing here, it's more conservative to initially start with the other two suggestions, as they merely check small header information. If those fail, don't exist, or aren't an option for whatever reason, _then_ fallback to the methods I linked, as those are significantly heavier across the spectrum of CPU/Memory/IO. Not to mention it's an import from outside the std libs, so more code as well.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear IsText doesn't works in windows

Comment: Do you read the file from a filesystem (which OS?) or do you receive it over the network (e.g. via HTTP)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to check that all the contents of the file is valid UTF-8

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {

        b, _ := os.ReadFile(os.Args[1])

        fmt.Println(utf8.ValidString(string(b)))

}
```

For really big files this would be inefficient, so an alternative might be to read the "first line" of the file and only check this

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    readFile, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(readFile)
    fileScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    fileScanner.Scan()

    fmt.Println(utf8.ValidString(string(fileScanner.Text())))

}
```

This second approach will sometimes fail - for example some installers have a script header followed by binary data - but in a lot of cases it would be fine

Comment: don't forget to close the file with `defer readFile.Close()`